# Vagrant ignores default box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I've been using Vagrant for some time without any problems.
Today I had a crash in a php application and I had to terminate vagrant and virtual box from Windows Task Manager.
Then I restarted my computer, but when running vagrant up, the virtual machine seemed to be starting from scratch, with a new provisioning, ignoring the box I've been using since then.
In the Virtual Box manager I found this new machine, while the old and correct one was powered off.
Can anyone help me to understand what happened, and restore the correct box?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is  possible to restore previous vagrant boxes.
Probably your VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH was erased/overwritten.

According to vagrant documentation:

> VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH can be set to change the directory where Vagrant stores VM-specific state, such as the VirtualBox VM UUID. By default, this is set to .vagrant. If you keep your Vagrantfile in a Dropbox folder in order to share the folder between your desktop and laptop (for example), Vagrant will overwrite the files in this directory with the details of the VM on the most recently-used host. To avoid this, you could set VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH to .vagrant-laptop and .vagrant-desktop on the respective machines. (Remember to update your .gitignore!)

So to avoid such situations in future you have to backup VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH directory.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately I had to create a brand new box e start a new enviroment. This time I'll be a little more cautious... Thank you anyway.